# How to mock a method in Java, if that method present in external jar?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am writing a junit for a method which is internally  calling following method :

```
extensionManager.registerPlugin(extension);
```

Here extensionManager is object of class of external jar. To do this, I tried the following :

```
ExtensionManager em = new ExtensionManager();
ExtensionManager emSpy = spy(em);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(emSpy, 
   "registerPlugin",Mockito.any());
```

Note : registerPlugin method has return type as void.

But this is not working for me. It is calling real method. Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: This is one of the (many) reasons it's useful to hide external implementations behind a locally-controlled interface.  If it's not too late, consider doing so.  Then testing your interaction with that library becomes trivial.

Comment: That said, the Mockito docs says you can mock concrete classes too... https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/index.html?org/mockito/Mockito.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of the mock itself looks correct but you haven't shown the full test especially how you use the create spy.

There are two things that you need to check.

Firstly, you need to make sure that the code that invokes `extensionManager.registerPlugin(extension);` uses the spy, that is `emSpy` object you created. The mocking here happens only for the instance of the object that you created. If your code under the test creates another `extensionManager` which you are not replacing in test the call will not be mocked and the real `registerPlugin` will be invoked.

The second thing is that if `registerPlugin` is private or `ExtensionManager` class is final you need to use `@PrepareForTest(ExtensionManager.class)` on your test class as described in [powermock documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#a-full-example-of-spying)

Comment: Thanks @Roman, Issue resolved. I was not using the same spy to invoke methid, that I have created.